# Casting Rc<ConcreteType> to an Rc<Trait>

Tags: casting, rust

`Horse` is a struct which implements the `Animal` trait. I have an `Rc<Horse>` and a function that needs to take in an `Rc<Animal>`, so I want to convert from `Rc<Horse>` to `Rc<Animal>`.

I did this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Horse;

trait Animal {}

impl Animal for Horse {}

fn main() {
    let horse = Rc::new(Horse);
    let animal = unsafe {
        // Consume the Rc<Horse>
        let ptr = Rc::into_raw(horse);
        // Now it's an Rc<Animal> pointing to the same data!
        Rc::<Animal>::from_raw(ptr)
    };
}
```

Is this a good solution? Is it correct?

Comment: There is a reason why I edited your post, please don't roll it back unless you think I did something wrong. [Removing fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) is appreciated by stackoverflow! Also there is not *'the best'* solution, so I changed it to *'a good'* solution which is better than asking for an absolute.

Comment: Edits that change sentiments or remove personal expressions feel uncomfortable to me and like putting words in my mouth. (Edits for clarity, correction, or for punctuation or spelling seem not weird). For instance: maybe you think there is no "best", but perhaps I do. In fact, I *do* think you're right, yet it is odd to see one's own writing changed. The norms of SO are what they are, so you must do as you see fit, and it is I who must conform. OTOH, I hope SO has taken into account a feeling that maybe others hold, too. I hope that you receive this comment as in the spirit of honest feedback.

Comment: I understand, but stackoverflow tries to be simple. A simple, well formed question, no phrasing around and no fluff. On the other hand answer should also be very straight and do not contain any unneeded things. I feel you, if you say, that the question is not your wording anymore, but I think, that is okay, because you are not asking only for yourself, but for everyone who has the same/simlar question and needs an answer. I hope you do understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [answer by Boiethios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276680/279627) already explains that upcasting can be explicitly performed using `as`, or even happens implicitly in certain situaions. I'd like to add a few more detail on the mechanisms.

I'll start with explaining why your unsafe code works correctly.

```
let animal = unsafe {
    let ptr = Rc::into_raw(horse);
    Rc::<Animal>::from_raw(ptr)
};
```

The first line in the `unsafe` block consumes `horse` and returns a `*const Horse`, which is a pointer to a concrete type. The pointer is exactly what you'd expect it to be – the memory address of `horse`'s data (ignoring the fact that in your example `Horse` is zero-sized and has no data). In the second line, we call `Rc::from_raw()`; let's look at the protoype of that function:

```
pub unsafe fn from_raw(ptr: *const T) -> Rc<T>
```

Since we are calling this function for `Rc::<Animal>`, the expected argument type is `*const Animal`. Yet the `ptr` we have has type `*const Horse`, so why does the compiler accept the code? The answer is that the compiler performs an *unsized coercion*, a type of implicit cast that is [performed in certain places for certain types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html). Specifically, we convert a pointer to a concrete type to a pointer to *any* type implementing the `Animal` trait. Since we don't know the exact type, now the pointer isn't a mere memory address anymore – it's a memory address together with an identifier of the actual type of the object, a so-called *fat pointer*. This way, the `Rc` created from the fat pointer can retain the information of the underlying concrete type, and can call the correct methods for `Horse`'s implementation of `Animal` (if there are any; in your example `Animal` doesn't have any functions, but of course this should continue to work if there are).

We can see the difference between the two kinds of pointer by printing their size

```
let ptr = Rc::into_raw(horse);
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&ptr));
let ptr: *const Animal = ptr;
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&ptr));
```

This code first makes `ptr` a `*const Horse`, prints the size of the pointer, then uses an unsized coercion to convert `ptr` to and `*const Animal` and prints its size again. On a 64-bit system, this will print

```
8
16
```

The first one is just a simple memory address, while the second one is a memory address together with information on the concrete type of the pointee. (Specifically, the fat pointer contains a pointer to the [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).)

Now let's look at what happens in the code in Boethios' answer

```
let animal = horse as Rc<Animal>;
```

or equivalently

```
let animal: Rc<Animal> = horse;
```

also perform an unsized coercion. How does the compiler know how to do this for a `Rc` rather than a raw pointer? The answer is that [the trait `CoerceUnsized` exists specifically for this purpose](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CRc%3CU%3E%3E). You can read the [RFC on coercions for dynamically sized types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I figured something like that must have been happening behind the scenes. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I *think* that your solution is correct, while I'm not a specialist for unsafe code. But, you do not have to use unsafe code to do such simple things as upcasting:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Animal {}

struct Horse;

impl Animal for Horse {}

fn main() {
    let horse = Rc::new(Horse);
    let animal = horse as Rc<Animal>;
}
```

If you want to pass it to a function, you do not even have to cast:

```
fn gimme_an_animal(_animal: Rc<Animal>) {}

fn main() {
    let horse = Rc::new(Horse);
    gimme_an_animal(horse);
}
```

Because `Horse` implements `Animal`, an horse **is** an animal. You do not have to do anything special for casting it. Note that this transformation is destructive, and you cannot make an `Rc<Horse>` from an `Rc<Animal>`.

Comment: Thank you; you are indeed correct. I had confused myself because I was using references to Rcs in my actual code, which made things more complicated.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You even can do `let animal: Rc<Animal> = horse`.